# Unknown Syntax Error when implementing Cloud Functions in the new AngularFire 7 (Firebase 9)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2

In app.module.ts

```
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
  ],
```

In my app.component

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private fns: Functions) {}

  hello() {
    httpsCallable(
      this.fns,
      'test'
    )('hello world').then(() => console.log('complete'));
  }
}
```

[image]

**This code works perfectly fine but why do I get this syntax error**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but shouldn't it be

```
import { AngularFireFunctions as Functions } from '@angular/fire/compat/functions';
```

instead?

Based on [functions docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/functions/functions.md).

So, it could be used as `this.fns.httpsCallable('test')`.

Comment: The doc u shared isnt updated for AngularFire7... For firebase 9+ this is how to implement it [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment)